# Get associated type object from enum without switch

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have an enum with associated types. All associated types conform a protocol. I want to reach a variable from that protocol without switching enum. How can I achieve this?

I want to get `position` object from enum element without switch.

```
protocol ComponentModelProtocol {
    var position: Int { get } //Describes in which stackview component will be. (0 means left, 1 means right)
    var isTappable: Bool { get } //Adds gesture recognizer to the view If this is true
}

enum ComponentType {
    case onelinetwolabel(content: LabelComponentModel)
    case twolinelabel(content: BoxComponentModel)
    case labelwithimage(content: BoxComponentModel)
    case currencySelector(content: CurrencySelectorModel)
    case seperator(position: Int)
}

struct CurrencySelectorModel: ComponentModelProtocol {
    let position: Int
    let isTappable: Bool
    let currencyArray: [String]
}

struct LabelComponentModel: ComponentModelProtocol {
    let key: String
    let value: String
    let position: Int
    let isTappable: Bool
    let labelType: OneLineTwoLabel.LabelType

    init(key: String, value: String, position: Int, isTappable: Bool, labelType: OneLineTwoLabel.LabelType) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.position = position
        self.isTappable = isTappable
        self.labelType = labelType
    }

    init(key: String, value: String, position: Int) {
        self.init(key: key,value: value,position: position, isTappable: false, labelType: .defaultLabel)
    }

    init(key: String, value: String, position: Int,isTappable: Bool) {
        self.init(key: key,value: value,position: position, isTappable: isTappable, labelType: .defaultLabel)
    }

}

//Struct for two line label component
struct BoxComponentModel: ComponentModelProtocol {
    let key: String
    let value: String
    let position: Int
    let isTappable: Bool

    init(key: String, value: String, position: Int,isTappable: Bool) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
        self.position = position
        self.isTappable = isTappable
    }

    init(key: String, value: String, position: Int) {
        self.init(key: key,value: value, position: position,isTappable: false)
    }
    }
```

I know I can do it with adding variable inside enum like below but It adds switch for every element. I'm looking for a more clever way If there is.

```
enum ComponentType: ComponentModelProtocol {
    var position: Int {
        switch self {
        case .onelinetwolabel(content: let model):
            return model.position
        case .twolinelabel(content: let model):
            return model.position
        case .labelwithimage(content: let model):
            return model.position
        case .currencySelector(content: let model):
            return model.position
        case .seperator(position: let position):
            return position
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way to access the associated value is by the rather hideous (IMO ) `if case let` syntax.

I'm not sure it'll make things any easier so I'll not go into depth here, but all the info you'll need on it is on [If Case Let syntax](http://goshdarnifcaseletsyntax.com/)

Comment: It is really a nice topic but I don't think It answers my question.